# How do I stop USB buffering?

Tags: windows, linux, usb

I'm reading real-time data over USB, but the data is buffered.  How do I stop the buffering?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Linux**

Use udev to change the latency_timer.

On ubuntu, create a rule in `/etc/udev/rules.d` for your device.  Eg `99-xsens.rules`

Create a rule in that file to match your device and set the latency_timer.  For example, for my device this is:

```
KERNEL=="ttyUSB[0-9]*", SUBSYSTEMS=="usb-serial", DRIVERS=="ftdi_sio", ATTR{device/latency_timer}="2"
```

This causes the device to wait a shorter time before deciding there's no more incoming data to buffer.  In this case my device went from waiting 16ms to waiting 2ms.

Use `udevadm info -a -n /dev/ttyUSB0`, for example, to find out what key-value pairs to match against in your rule.  There are some tricky things to keep in mind, but finding resources to help with the ins and outs was easy once I knew to use udev rules.

Here's a good reference page on [writing udev rules](http://reactivated.net/writing_udev_rules.html).  It is old and the syntax of the udev tools has changed, but the concepts are still valid.

**Windows**

On Windows you use `Device Manager->Ports->COM Port->Port Settings->Advanced->Latency Timer`.

Comment: Sorry for the zombie reply, but why does modifying the com port settings have any effect on buffering USB read operations?